# ICEfaces libary in classpath prevents Save As dialog from popping up on file download

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, download, icefaces

As soon as I add the librarys icefaces.jar icepush.jar icefaces_ace.jar to my classpath in order to use ACE components, my SaveAs dialog won't popup? I'm not sure if this is a bug but without the librarys in classpath it works. Here's my save as method :

```
    public void downloadFile(String propertyPath) throws IOException {

     ProxyFile fileToDownload = repBean.downloadFile(propertyPath);

     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
     HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

     response.reset();         response.setContentType(fileToDownload.getContentType()); 
     response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(fileToDownload.getLength()));
     response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileToDownload.getName() + "\""); 

     BufferedInputStream input = null;
     BufferedOutputStream output = null;


     try {
         input = new BufferedInputStream(fileToDownload.getContent());
         output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

         byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
         for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }
     } finally {
         output.close();
         input.close();
         facesContext.responseComplete(); 
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't download files using ajax.

Ajax is under the covers executed by JavaScript's `XMLHttpRequest` object. The request will be successfully executed and the response will be successfully retrieved. However, JavaScript has no facility to write the response to client's disk file system, nor to force a *Save As* dialogue with the given response. That would be a huge security breach.

The cause of your concrete problem is ICEfaces itself. Namely, when you integrate ICEfaces in a JSF web application, all standard `<h:commandXxx>` links/buttons will silently be turned into ajax-enabled ones which indeed causes confusion among starters. Make sure that the download link/button isn't implicitly using ICEfaces-introduced ajax facility. As per their [wiki page on the subject](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Disabling+Ajax), you need to explicitly nest a `<f:ajax disabled="true">` to disable this.

> #### Disable Ajax for a Component
>
> You can also disable Ajax at the level of the individual component:
>
> ```
> <h:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{bean.sendMessage}">
>     <f:ajax disabled="true"/>
> </h:commandButton>
> ```

Apply it on your download link/button.

Comment: It works you are the best ;) But I really only added the libraries to the classpath so there must be something going on in the background I don't know.

Comment: You're welcome. Click the wiki page link for an explanation what ICEfaces is doing.