# invoke two methods after h:commandLink click in JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to invoke two methods in two other tags after `h:commandLink` click. I use JSF2 and RichFaces 4.3.7.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="print" 
    action="#{PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc}"
     status="waitStatus">
</a4j:jsFunction>

<h:commandLink value="${msg['page.dfeOper016form.button.printAll']}" 
    target="_blank"  
    disabled="#{not PDFReportsMBean.selectedAnyDocs}"
    action="#{PDFReportsMBean.prepareData}">
</h:commandLink>

<a4j:ajax event="click" oncomplete="print()"/>
```

This code does not work... Coluld anyone help me?

Comment: Is `printSelectedScannedDoc` supposed to perform a file download?

Comment: Exactly, `printSelectedScannedDoc` method downloads zip file

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to perform a file download using Ajax as you're trying to do. Ajax uses javascript under the covers, which has limitations of file writing permissions. Your best chance is to wrap the whole logic in a single method or, alternativelly, use an `actionListener`:

```
<h:commandLink value="${msg['page.dfeOper016form.button.printAll']}" 
    target="_blank"  
    disabled="#{not PDFReportsMBean.selectedAnyDocs}"
    actionListener="#{PDFReportsMBean.prepareData}" 
    action="#{PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc}"/>
```

**See also:**

- [Download file with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13478920/1199132)
- [Differences between `action` and `actionListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/1199132)

Comment: It is not solution for me bacuse after PDFReportsMBean.prepareData and before 'PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc' method I must re-render some elements in my page...

Comment: Which behaviour are you expecting? Something similar to the Primefaces' [download monitor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml)?

Comment: In the `PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc` I invoke : 
`HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

response.reset()` and I must rerender elements before `PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc`... I cant not change `PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc` method code because my app uses this method in a few places...