# p:fileDownload not working with h:head

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, download, facelets, head

I have a `<p:download>` like this:

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"   
        icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s" actionListener="#{search.downloadActionListener}">   
        <p:fileDownload value="#{search.dwnloadFile}" />  
    </p:commandButton> 
</h:form>
```

It doesn't work. The download button just reloads the page and doesn't show the *Save As* dialog. After checking every single thing, I came to know that if I remove the `<h:head>` tag from the page, then it starts to work.

I can't work without `<h:head>` as PrimeFaces look'n'feel and all ajax functionality depends on it.

---

**Update**: the generated HTML `<head>` with `<h:head>` is like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/theme.css.xhtml?ln=icefaces.ace" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Project2.0/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml?db=eAG7mShzEgAFjAIg" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/dock/dock.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/dock/dock.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/icepush.js.xhtml?v=9261182" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/bridge.js.xhtml?v=9261182" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.isHeadUpdateSuccessful=true;</script>
    <style type="text/css">.ice-blockui-overlay {position: absolute;background-color: white;z-index: 28000;opacity: 0.22;filter: alpha(opacity = 22);}.ice-status-indicator-overlay {position: absolute;background-color: white;z-index: 28000;opacity: 0.22;filter: alpha(opacity = 22);}</style>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/compat.js.xhtml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/icefaces-compat.js.xhtml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>
        Project
    </title>
    <link href="../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

and without `<h:head>` it's like this:

```
<head>
    <title>
        Project
    </title>
    <link href="../Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: compare the header of both HTML documents, see if anything is missing/overwritten from the working page to the non-working one.

Comment: i checked html of both which is different.I am unable to understand this as i am still new in JSF and web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML output of the `<h:head>` suggests that you're mixing PrimeFaces with ICEfaces. The main cause of your concrete problem is this script from ICEfaces:

```
<script src="/Project2.0/javax.faces.resource/icefaces-compat.js.xhtml" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[This basically turns every non-ajax submit button into an ajax submit button](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Disabling+Ajax). This also includes the download button. But you cannot download files with ajax.

Remove ICEfaces altogether. You don't need it. [It's basically a clone of PrimeFaces 2.x](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1692). But if you're already using PrimeFaces 3.x, then ICEfaces has utterly no additional value. Perhaps it was a leftover from previous experimenting with various JSF component libraries.

#### See also:

- [ICEfaces libary in classpath prevents Save As dialog from popping up on file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420958/ice-faces-libary-in-classpath-prevents-saveas-dialog-from-popping-up/13422428#13422428)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the HTML output also suggests that you're also having RichFaces in the runtime classpath. Whilst that should theoretically work fine together with PrimeFaces, I wouldn't recommend mixing them. RichFaces has in essence nothing which PrimeFaces doesn't already offer.

Comment: "It's basically a clone". True, hahaha

Comment: Thanks alot for detail explanation. Actually i am using fileupload tag of icefaces which i found easier than primefaces tag. I guess i have to use primefaces fileupload now.