# Jsf file download doesn't work

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, icefaces

When I click the `h:commandButton` it execute the `myBean.dowanlod()` method, but it doesn't download any files.
Here is my methods in the backing bean. No exceptions. Cursor gets busy and seems like waiting for a response. Are there any additional configurations for this kind of operations or is there any wrong with this code?

```
<h:commandButton value="download" action="#{myBean.download()}" /> 

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped    
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
   //....

   public String download{

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

    String fileName = "test.txt";
    String filePath = "D:\\test.txt"; //externalContext.getRealPath("") + File.separator + fileName;
    File file = new File(filePath);

    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");


    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        output = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(input, output);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
    }

    facesContext.responseComplete();
    return null;
  }

  //...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICEfaces has the strange "[feature](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Disabling+Ajax)" that it implicitly converts all standard JSF `<h:commandButton>` to ajax-enabled command buttons. However, it's not possible to download files using ajax. You need to explicitly turn it off. You can do that on a per-button basis by nesting a `<f:ajax disabled="true">`.

```
<h:commandButton value="download" action="#{myBean.download()}" />
    <f:ajax disabled="true"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [p:fileDownload not working with h:head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373078/pfiledownload-not-working-with-hhead)
- [ICEfaces libary in classpath prevents Save As dialog from popping up on file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420958/ice-faces-libary-in-classpath-prevents-saveas-dialog-from-popping-up/)

Comment: If it is about JSF, BalusC should be there :)

Comment: Can you give me some help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104690/prevent-caching-data-of-a-datatable. I have lots of trouble with it.

Comment: Thank you! Same problem here, in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had `<h:head>` and `<ice:form>`. This file download thing doesn't work with those namespaces. Just using `<head>` and `<h:form>` resolve the problem. I'm learning JSF, so I have no idea about this. Somehow it works for me.
And I found much better file download tutorial from [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/05/pdf-handling.html). If anyone knows or can guess the reason please give some ideas.